# How do I return JSON in my Node.js proxy?

Tags: json, node.js, https, mongoose

I had to proxy the requests to the Dota 2 API. After some research I found a way to do it in the API I am building using the MEAN stack. However, I can't figure out how to return the data from the request.

Here is my route in my node server code:

```
   router.get('/api/allheros', function (req, res) {
    Https.get('https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=FB900D42DC33F4B4FCC62F6C7779BE5D', function (res) {
        var str = '';
        console.log('Response is ' + res.statusCode);

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str); //This console logs all the heros correctly
        });

    });
});
```

The console log works but I need the data to be returned to the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is parse your result into a JSON Object and send it back using `res.json()`. Modify your code as follows,

```
router.get('/api/allheros', function (req, res) {
    Https.get('https://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetHeroes/v0001/?key=FB900D42DC33F4B4FCC62F6C7779BE5D', function (response) {
        var str = '';
        console.log('Response is ' + response.statusCode);

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            res.json(JSON.parse(str)); 
        });

    });
});
```

Note: The `res` in inner function had to be changed to `response` so that it doesn't mask the `res` parameter of outer function.

Comment: Is `console.log('Response is ' + res.statusCode);` or `console.log('Response is ' + response.statusCode);`?

Comment: aah, its `console.log('Response is ' + response.statusCode);` I missed that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answers. However, the response in postman looks like this: '"\"{\\n\\t\"result\": {\\n\\t\\t\"heroes\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\"name\": '. Do I just evaluate it?

Comment: make it JSON.parse(), instead of JSON.stringify. As long as your response is proper JSON it will work.